# How can I further improve this model(autoencoder)?

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

This is the first time I am implementing an autocoder for image clustering and I'm new to CNN.
I try to understand how it works and learn by testing the model with images. This is my model and I just want to know if there is anything wrong I am doing here or if you have any suggestion that could improve this model.

```
input = Input((224, 224,3), name = 'input')

conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(input)
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(conv1)
bn1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
pool_enc = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2))(bn1)
conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(bn1)
bn1 = BatchNormalization()(bn1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2))(bn1)

#DECODER

pool1 = UpSampling2D((2,2))(pool1)
bn1 = BatchNormalization()(pool1)
bn1 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'')(bn1)
opt = Adam(lr=0.01)

model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = bn1, name = 'a-coder')

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The word "improve" is very vague since you really need to specify exactly what wrong with it currently and how will you measure the "improvement".

But the first thing I'd do with your code is rearranging the layers.

The best way to put CNN layers together is a

```
a CNN -> a Batch Normalization -> an activation (like relu)
```

While what you're doing now is like

```
a CNN -> a relu -> a CNN -> a relu -> a Batch Normalization
```

Which is less than ideal.

The encoder part should look like

```
conv5_enc = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name ='conv5_1_enc')(pool4_enc)
conv5_enc = BatchNormalization(name = "bn5_enc_1")(conv5_enc)
conv5_enc = Activation('relu')(conv5_enc)
conv5_enc = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name ='conv5_2_enc')(conv5_enc)
conv5_enc = BatchNormalization(name = "bn5_enc_2")(conv5_enc)
conv5_enc = Activation('relu')(conv5_enc)
conv5_enc = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name ='conv5_3_enc')(conv5_enc)
conv5_enc = BatchNormalization(name = "bn5_enc_3")(conv5_enc)
conv5_enc = Activation('relu')(conv5_enc)
```

Decoder too, there's no point using batchnorm before cnn

```
pool2_dec = UpSampling2D((2,2), name = 'pool_2')(conv3_dec)
conv2_dec = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name ='conv2_2_dec')(pool2_dec)
conv2_dec = BatchNormalization(name = "bn4_dec_1")(conv2_dec)
conv2_dec = Activation('relu')(conv2_dec)
conv2_dec = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name ='conv2_1_dec')(conv2_dec)
conv2_dec = BatchNormalization(name = "bn4_dec_2")(conv2_dec)
conv2_dec = Activation('relu')(conv2_dec)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I missed that it should be conv+batch normalization+relu as you mentioned. And you are right about bn in decoder because the result was better without bn in decoder because I used bn wrongly but what about this model https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11277-018-5702-9/figures/4 Didn't they use bn and relu in decoder in this case?